# Configuring Jackson mapper when using Dropwizard

Tags: json, jackson, jersey, dropwizard

I would like to use the [Java 8 java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) with Jersey/Jackson in the context of a [Dropwizard](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.5/docs/index.html) app. I understand I need to use [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime) and configure the mapper object.

But how do I configure Jersey's automagic mapper that deserialises the incoming JSON for me? I.e. where would I do `mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());`?

To illustrate the current situation here is an example class that represents the incoming JSON:

```
public class Example {
  // Want to use java.time instead
  private Date date;
  private final String ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME = "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ssZ";

  @JsonCreator
  public Example(@JsonProperty("date") 
                 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME) 
                 Date date) {
    this.date = date;
  }

  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)
  public Date getDate() {
    return date;
  }
}
```

As you can see that uses the older Date API. The Jersey resources looks like the following:

```
@Path("/example")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ExampleResource {
  @POST
  public void consume(Example example) {
    // Do stuff with example.date
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`JavaTimeModule` is [registered by default](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/c3c833820c4a638f088054edb3ca58b0576ba9a5/dropwizard-jackson/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jackson/Jackson.java#L55-L70) in Dropwizard 1.0.0 and above. For previous versions, the [dropwizard-java8](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard-java8) bundle provided support for Java 8 features. Java 8 is the baseline for Dropwizard 1.0.0, and the bundle was [merged into baseline](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.0/docs/about/release-notes.html#v1-0-0-jul-26-2016).

Assuming you use Dropwizard 1.0.0 or above, if you still need to access the `ObjectMapper`, you can do it in your `Application<T>`:

- in method `void initialize(Bootstrap<T> bootstrap)`, via `bootstrap.getObjectMapper()`
- in method `abstract void run(T configuration, Environment environment)`, via `environment.getObjectMapper()`

That way, you can register other modules, or enable or disable Jackson features. Some of them impact [how Java 8 types are serialized and deserialized](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime#summary).